# How to bypass this Transaction check error

Tags: centos, yum

I have this error when I use `yum update`

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp from install of npm-1:3.1         0.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.e         l7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/doc from install of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64          conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/html from install of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_6         4 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man from install of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64          conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansi-regex from install of npm-1:3         .10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource         .el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansicolors from install of npm-1:3         .10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource         .el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles from install of npm-1:3         .10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource         .el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/archy from install of npm-1:3.10.3         -107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.         centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/chownr from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim from install of npm-1:3.1         0.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.e         l7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify from install of npm-1:3.         10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.         el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain from install of npm-1         :3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesour         ce.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo from install of npm-1:3.10         .3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el         7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/editor from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-vacuum from install of npm-1:3.         10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.         el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-write-stream-atomic from instal         l of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0         -1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream from install of npm-1:3.10         .3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el         7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream-npm from install of npm-1:         3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesourc         e.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob from install of npm-1:3.10.3-         107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.c         entos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs from install of npm-1:         3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesourc         e.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/hosted-git-info from install of np         m-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodes         ource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/imurmurhash from install of npm-1:         3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesourc         e.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight from install of npm-1:3.1         0.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.e         l7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inherits from install of npm-1:3.1         0.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.e         l7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ini from install of npm-1:3.10.3-1         07.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.ce         ntos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/init-package-json from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nod         esource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile from install of npm-1:3.1         0.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.e         l7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt from install of npm-1:3.10.3-         107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.c         entos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-git-url from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nod         esource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data from instal         l of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0         -1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-cache-filename from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1no         desource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1no         desource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg from install of np         m-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodes         ource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client from install o         f npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1n         odesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream from install of np         m-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodes         ource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/retry from install of npm-1:3.10.3         -107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.         centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-user-validate from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nod         esource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once from install of npm-1:3.10.3-         107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.c         entos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/opener from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv from install of npm-1:3.10.3         -107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.         centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/path-is-inside from install of npm         -1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodeso         urce.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read from install of npm-1:3.10.3-         107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.c         entos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed from install of npm         -1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodeso         urce.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nod         esource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/realize-package-specifier from ins         tall of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.         5.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request from install of npm-1:3.10         .3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el         7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha from install of npm-1:3.10.3-1         07.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.ce         ntos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide from install of npm-1:3.10.3         -107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.         centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sorted-object from install of npm-         1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesou         rce.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/strip-ansi from install of npm-1:3         .10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource         .el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar from install of npm-1:3.10.3-1         07.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.ce         ntos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table from install of npm-1:3         .10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource         .el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number from install of npm-1:3         .10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource         .el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/umask from install of npm-1:3.10.3         -107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.         centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license from          install of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1         :4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/validate-npm-package-name from ins         tall of npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.         5.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which from install of npm-1:3.10.3         -107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7.         centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/wrappy from install of npm-1:3.10.         3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nodesource.el7         .centos.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/write-file-atomic from install of          npm-1:3.10.3-107.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nodejs-1:4.5.0-1nod         esource.el7.centos.x86_64
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

my quick solution was:

```
# yum erase nodejs
# yum install nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

short:

```
# yum reinstall nodejs
```

;-)